# How can I fix Xpath in Importjson function?

Tags: arrays, json, xpath, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I want to get list algo from JSON response. In google sheet I am using this command:

```
IMPORTJSON("http://miningpoolhub.com/index.php?page=api&action=getminingandprofitsstatistics", "return/algo")
```

But I got the message "*Nod not available*" I think I have done something wrong with the Xpath command. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean "node not available"? Please add a sample of the XML into your question as well. Is `return/algo` the XPath expression you are using?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? I thought that `/` is required to be added to the top of path.

```
=IMPORTJSON("http://miningpoolhub.com/index.php?page=api&action=getminingandprofitsstatistics", "/return/algo")
```

If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.